# numpy indexing: fixed length parts of each row with varying starting column

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array like `z` and a 1d array denoting the "start column position" like `starts`. In addition I have a fixed `row_length = 2`

```
z = np.arange(35).reshape(5, -1)
# --> array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
             [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
             [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
             [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
             [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]])

starts = np.array([1,5,3,3,2])
```

What I want is the outcome of this slow for-loop, just quicker if possible.

```
result = np.zeros(
    (z.shape[0], row_length), 
    dtype=z.dtype
)
for i in range(z.shape[0]):
    s = starts[i]
    result[i] = z[i, s:s+row_length]
```

So `result` in this example should look like this in the end:

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [12, 13],
       [17, 18],
       [24, 25],
       [30, 31]])
```

I can't seem to find a way using either fancy indexing or `np.take` to deliver this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to get those indices using [`broadcasted additions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with those `starts` and `row_length` and then use [`NumPy's advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to extract out all of those elements off the data array, like so -

```
idx = starts[:,None] + np.arange(row_length)
out = z[np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [197]: z
Out[197]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
       [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]])

In [198]: starts = np.array([1,5,3,3,2])

In [199]: row_length = 2

In [200]: idx = starts[:,None] + np.arange(row_length)

In [202]: z[np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
Out[202]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [12, 13],
       [17, 18],
       [24, 25],
       [30, 31]])
```